Beamsplitter and hardware for event-frame camera

I'm planning to build a high resolution event-frame camera like in the image above. I'm going to use a Triton2 RGB camera and a Silkeyevcam.
I'm having trouble figuring out what beamsplitter and mounting hardware I need. The setup in this paper is basically what I'm going for. The people at Thorlabs suggested a pellicle beam splitter like this. But I think I need something more like this 50R/50T VIS, C-Mounted Plate Beamsplitter.
Am I on the right track with the beamsplitter? What hardware do I need to interface the cameras and lenses with the beamsplitter?
